# Where is the Android SDK offline documentation for frameworks beyond API level 24?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to find the Android SDK offline docs for API level 28. I have installed both the "Android SDK Platform 28" and "Sources for Android 28" using the SDK Manager, but I cannot find the documentation. When I load up ~/Library/Android/sdk/docs/index.html, and go to Develop::Reference, and try to select the API level, it only goes up to API level 24. Are the docs for more modern SDK versions somewhere else?

[image: SDK Manager]
[image: Offline Docs page]

Comment: I suspect that they stopped offering those. The current site seems very dependent on async loading from their server, and the offline docs have always been derived from the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The offline documentation is not updated anymore, everything in the `AndroidSDK\docs` folder has not been updated after Nougat release (API 24) and I don't think it will ever be.

You need to go to the official site to see the updated documentation.

Comment: Nope, no way currently :(